# no route matches error at file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm having a no route matches error after a render :partial

```
<% unless @user.uploads.empty? %>
 <% @user.uploads.each do |u| %>
 <tr>
 <td><%= link_to u.filename, u.filename %></td>
```

it gives me the right filename like http://localhost:3000/DSC00082.JPG.
i haven't added anything to my routes.
for being new to rails, please excuse my (hopefully) easy question.

to add a question: is it right for the corresponding database entry to be just the filename?

after changing above code to

```
<% unless @user.uploads.empty? %>
 <% @user.uploads.each do |uploads| %>
 <tr>
 <td><%= link_to (uploads.filename, uploads) %></td>
```

and adding map.rescources :upload,
a "No action responded to show" message was generated. in the adress bar, my browser shows the id of the regarding dataset.

Greetings,
devyn

Comment: what is your render :partial code?

Comment: render partial code is in index; above code coming from _datafiles

    <%= render :partial => 'upload/datafiles' %>

Answer (score 0):

If `u` is a subclass of `ActiveRecord::Base`, your link_to has to be like this:

```
<%= link_to u.filename, u %>
```

The same Rails would detect that `u` is an object with controller, and it will convert it to a REST valid URL (and redirect you to the show action).

If this isn't your scenario, please tell me.

[EDIT]

If you know how Rails work, skip this paragraph:

With map.resources :upload you are telling rails that you have a resource called Upload that has a UploadController, and generates routes for 5 actions: `new/create, index, show, edit/update` and `destroy`. Each action needs a method in the controller(See the ClientsController example in [Rails Guides](http://guides.rails.info/action_controller_overview.html)).

"No action responded to show" raises when you don't have `UploadsController#show`. An example of this method:

```
def show
  @upload = Upload.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xml {render :xml => @upload}
  end
end
```

This method render a the file views/uploads/show (be sure of create it).

Comment: unfortunately, this throws an "undefined method `upload_path'" message; even after changing all regarding "u" to "upload(s)".

Comment: Your config/routes.rb has the line "  map.resources :uploads  " (Without the quotes) ?

Comment: please see edited post above. it has to be rescources :upload for my controller is named that way